# add common prefix to logstash output for given filter

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash

Im working with some logstash io that generates lots of fields with names like 'a0', 'a1'. I can mutate these but there are *lots* of them so I'd like to prepend a 'namespace' (of sorts) to all the fields from a filter.

IE if the parsed records are 'a0' and 'a1' Id like them to appear in elasticsearch as 'somespace.a0' and 'somespace.a1'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if you are using the **kv** filter you can add a 'prefix' (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-prefix)).

```
prefix:

Value type is string
Default value is ""
A string to prepend to all of the extracted keys.

For example, to prepend arg_ to all keys:

filter { kv { prefix => "arg_" } }
```